# https://www.domain.com won't redirect to https://domain.com on VPS

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I have this on my Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
other stuff here
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works great. It redirects all `www.example.com` => `https://example.com`.
But the issue is if a visitor types `https://www.example.com` then the redirect doesn't happen.

I added the same line under the 443 VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
other stuff here
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesnt have the same effect any ideas please?

Comment: what do you get if you go to the ssl site? the site with www added still?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:443>
> other stuff here
> Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ 
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Assuming your SSL cert covers both the `www` subdomain and the apex domain then it's your "other stuff" that is important here - this will be what determines what host you are redirecting *from*.

> is if a visitor types `https://www.example.com` then the redirect doesnt happen.

For this to happen, you need to have a VirtualHost container that specifically targets port 443 *and* covers the host `www.example.com` (ie. including the `www` subdomain). This should be a separate VirtualHost setup just for the purpose of redirecting. For example, this would need to include the appropriate `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive:

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

> I added the same line under **the** 443 VirtualHost

You will need two VirtualHosts for port 443. One for `www.example.com` that redirects (as mentioned above) and one for your canonical `example.com` that contains all your config.